# PHP compare result of two tables

Tags: php, mysql, compare

I have two tables with this structure:

Table one:
ID      Description

Table two:
ID      Name

I have to echo only the id's of both tables but i don't know how to compare.
i can show my idea using a stupid example:

```
if($id is in the first table  AND $id is in the second table){
echo $id;
echo $description;
echo $name
}
```

How to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: what database do you have ?? MYSQL or Oracle??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT t1.*,t2.* FROM table1 as t1, table2 as t2 WHERE t1.id=t2.id AND t1.id='$id'")
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
   echo $data["id"];
   echo $data["description"];
   echo $data["name"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try below

`select one.id from myTableOne one, myTableTwo two WHERE one.id=two.id`

This will give the list of ids that are present in both tables...

Good Luck!!!

Answer (score 2):

use this query,

```
SELECT 
    T1.ID, 
    T1.Description, 
    T2.Name 
FROM
    `TableOne` AS `T1`
INNER JOIN 
    `TableTwo` AS `T2`
ON 
    (T1.ID=T2.ID)
```